# IP verification in batch script - first match by findstr, secondly verify by for loops (only using windows built in functinallity?

Tags: function, batch-file, for-loop, verification, findstr

This is a question for the batch pro's i guess. Seems a lot of people do stumble over IP veriffication while batching, while just using windows built in functinallity, but no real code is to find.

At several places a findstr expression is findable, to identify a numerical string matching four sequences of numbers.

```
findstr /r "[0-9][0-9]*\.[0-9][0-9]*\.[0-9][0-9]*\.[0-9][0-9]*"
```

While there seems no better way to identify the string itself (because of limited regular expression support of findstr) this catches too false positives like `1234.2.3.4` or `999.999.999.999` and of course `0.0.0.0`.

It would "only" need to verify the found string further, e.g. with a sequence of for loops, and `make shure each found string octet is valid for IP rules.

- first octet between `1 and 254`
- second and
- third between `0 and 255`
- forth between `1 and 254`

If one would then integrate a second part of verification into this code to identify further if found IP was one of the 3 private classes (`10.0.0.0/8, 172.16.0.0/12 and 192.168.0.0/16` or to be precice one of: 10.0.0.0 to 10.255.255.255, 172.16.0.0 to 172.31.255.255 and 192.168.0.0 to 192.168.255.255) this would make a round function. And not to forget the special 127.x.x.x must get warned D).

To get IP4 complete a switch to choose if private or public IP shall get verified and returnvalues may tell closer what kind or even subnet masks have been recognized:

- first octet must be `255`
- second and
- third and
- fourth one of `0,128,192,224,240,248,252,254,255`

**So overall this would be the pseudo routine:**

a function taking input, no matter where from, just to be called, taking switch for usage and returning result

- **take Switches for private or public IP range**
- **validate IP Syntax**

  - **IP verification - recognized range and set return values**

    - **private or**
    - **pulic class**
    - **subnet**
    - **...**
- **set returnvalue, set errorlevel depending on switch**

If the code does set nice usable return codes (like in example, return the recognized ip range) this would be an alltime function for everybody dealing with IP4's anyway. While i will extend those ip ranges myself, if only just the function will reliable return those "_return"-values like in example code.

Did i forget something?

Nobody did code this already?

**SOLUTION:**
According to MC ND's example and Aacini's switch handling and subnetmask code i blew up the code, added errorhandling usage echo and other cases - here with some testing sample code included:

```
  @echo off
          setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

          rem try some ip addresses 
          for %%i in ("1.2.3.4" "0.1.2.3" "250.1024.1.2" "10.0.2.1" "127.0.0.1" "1.2.3.255" "172.16.17.18" "192.168.1.1" "255.128.240.0" "0.0.0.0" "something" "" ) do (
          REM 1.2.3.4 is public / 0.1.2.3 is false all / 10.0.2.1 is private / 127.0.0.1 is local / 172.16.17.18 is private / 192.168.1.1 is private / 255.128.240.0 is subnet / 0.0.0.0 is false all (source net)


              echo --------------- run one as default case assuming pulic with ret var -------------------

              rem call default with a return variable 
              call :validateIP %%~i ret && echo %%i is valid || echo %%i is invalid
              echo return value: !ret!
              echo --------------------------------------------

              echo --------------- run two with switch public -------------------

              rem call with switch public 
              call :validateIP %%~i /public && echo %%i is valid || echo %%i is invalid
              echo return value: !ret!
              echo --------------------------------------------

              echo ------------ run three with switch private ---------------------
              rem call with switch private 
              call :validateIP %%~i /private && echo %%i is valid || echo %%i is invalid
              echo return value: !ret!
              echo --------------------------------------------

              echo ------------ run four with switch private and ret variable ---------------------
              rem call with switch private and return variable
              call :validateIP %%~i /private ret && echo %%i is valid || echo %%i is invalid
              echo return value: !ret!
              echo --------------------------------------------

              echo ------------ run five with switch local and ret variable ---------------------
              rem call with switch private and return variable
              call :validateIP %%~i /local ret && echo %%i is valid || echo %%i is invalid
              echo return value: !ret!
              echo --------------------------------------------

              echo ------------ run six with switch subnet and ret variable ---------------------
              rem call with switch private and return variable
              call :validateIP %%~i /subnet ret && echo %%i is valid || echo %%i is invalid
              echo return value: !ret!
              echo --------------------------------------------

              echo ------------ run seven with switch source and ret variable ---------------------
              rem call with switch private and return variable
              call :validateIP %%~i /source ret && echo %%i is valid || echo %%i is invalid
              echo return value: !ret!
              echo --------------------------------------------

              echo ------------ run eight with nothing ---------------------
              rem call with switch private and return variable
              call :validateIP && echo is valid || echo is invalid
              echo return value: !ret!
              echo --------------------------------------------

          )   
          exit /b 


 :validateIP ipAddress [/ipRange] [returnVariable]

  rem prepare environment
  setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion 


  if "%~1"=="" goto USAGE
  echo %~1| findstr /b /e /r "[0-9][0-9]*\.[0-9][0-9]*\.[0-9][0-9]*\.[0-9][0-9]*" >nul
  if errorlevel 1 goto USAGE
  :afterusage

  rem Initialize ip range as public
  set "ipCASE=public"

  rem Process switches
  set "returnVar=%~2"
  rem If second parameter start with slash...
  if "%returnVar:~0,1%" equ "/" (
      rem It is the /ipRange
      set "ipCASE=%returnVar:~1%"
      set "returnVar=%~3"
  )

  rem asume failure in tests : 0=pass 1=fail : same for return/errorlevel
  set "_return=1"
  set "_returnlevel=1"
  set "subNETNumbers=0,128,192,224,240,248,252,254,255"

  rem test if address conforms to ip address structure
  echo %~1| findstr /b /e /r "[0-9][0-9]*\.[0-9][0-9]*\.[0-9][0-9]*\.[0-9][0-9]*" >nul

  rem if it conforms to structure, test each octet for range values
  if not errorlevel 1 for /f "tokens=1-4 delims=." %%a in ("%~1") do (
      if %%a gtr 0 if %%a lss 255 if %%b leq 255 if %%c leq 255 if %%d gtr 0 if %%d leq 254 set "_return=public"
      if %%a equ 10 if %%b geq 0 if %%b lss 255 if %%c geq 0 if %%c lss 255 if %%d gtr 0 if %%d leq 254 set "_return=private"
      if %%a equ 172 if %%b geq 16 if %%b lss 31 if %%c geq 0 if %%c lss 255 if %%d gtr 0 if %%d leq 254 set "_return=private"
      if %%a equ 192 if %%b equ 168 if %%c geq 0 if %%c lss 255 if %%d gtr 0 if %%d leq 254 set "_return=private"
      if %%a equ 127 if %%b geq 0 if %%b lss 255 if %%c geq 0 if %%c lss 255 if %%d gtr 0 if %%d leq 254 set "_return=local"
      if %%a equ 255 if not "!subNETNumbers:%%b=!" equ "%subNETNumbers%" if not "!subNETNumbers:%%c=!" equ "%subNETNumbers%" if not "!subNETNumbers:%%d=!" equ "%subNETNumbers%" set "_return=subnetmask"
      if %%a equ 0 set "_return=sourcenetwork"
  )

  rem set returnlevels depending on given switch
  if "%ipCASE%"=="public"  if "%_return%"=="public"  (set "_returnlevel=0") else (set "_returnlevel=1")

  if "%ipCASE%"=="private" if "%_return%"=="private" (set "_returnlevel=0") else (set "_returnlevel=1")

  if "%ipCASE%"=="local" if "%_return%"=="local" (set "_returnlevel=0") else (set "_returnlevel=1")

  if "%ipCASE%"=="subnet" if "%_return%"=="subnetmask" (set "_returnlevel=0") else (set "_returnlevel=1")

  if "%ipCASE%"=="source" if "%_return%"=="sourcenetwork" (set "_returnlevel=0") else (set "_returnlevel=1")

  REM OPTION1 set errorlevel
  REM another correct way to set errorlevel would be to REM this line beneath and instead use _returnlevel with exit /b like in line REM OPTION2 - while this is interesting way to set it indirectly
  if "%_returnlevel%"=="0" (ver > nul) else (set dummy 2> nul)


  :endValidateIP
  rem clean and return data/errorlevel to caller
  endlocal & ( if not "%returnVar%"=="" set "%returnVar%=%_return%" ) & exit /b 
  REM OPTION2 endlocal & ( if not "%returnVar%"=="" set "%returnVar%=%_return%" ) & exit /b %_returnlevel%  

  :usage
  echo.
  echo   Usage:  call :validateIP [/ipRange] [returnVariable]
  echo.   
  echo        for example: call :validateIP 127.0.0.2 /local ret 
  echo.   
  echo     if NO switch is given function assumes public, 
  echo     switch and return var are optional
  echo     errorlevel depends and corresponds on given switch
  echo     known switches: /public, /private, /local, /subnet, /source
  echo     return var reflects syntax check, if return var is "1" the input was malformed anyhow
  echo.
  goto :afterusage
```

Comment: Feel like I should point out--for completeness--that depending on the versions of Windows you are running on, PowerShell may also be available. You'll have access to .NET's `Regex` as well as other libraries for manipulating IP addresses. Might make this task easier, *if you can use it*.

Comment: You only forgot to indicate if the IP strings may appear _at any place_ inside the lines returned by `findstr`...

Comment: @Aacini i did use false wording in first pseudo line by "find" the find was only in use to validate the octet syntax in first place like MC ND used it then in his code.

Comment: @Aacini Could you gimme a real function structure with switches in a better way than i tried simplyfied, not so say primitive :) I'd fill it up with the ip-definitions then? I am stuck with the handling of set vars (given to function from user) or not and cases.

Comment: @peet: Excuse me. I am in no way an IP4 expert. I don't know terms like "subnet mask", "private or public class", etc. Of course, I could learn on this theme in order to understand your request, but I have no reason to do so... However, if you state your problem in plain English and give _precise_ instructions on the operations/checking to achieve over each part (or group of parts), then I think I could write such code. Also, I don't know what to do with requests like "the code set nice usable return codes"; just state _which_ value you want be returned in each case.

Comment: @Aacini My Problem is not to code the ip range identifications and setting the "_return", like in example code - my problem is to get the switches and return values for the function working. Too as both switch and returnvalue variable shall be optional.

Comment: @peet: This was NOT the original question! I think it is a bad idea to modify a question in order to get answers to several different problems in the same topic. Anyway, see my _new_ answer to your _new_ question below... `:-(`

Comment: @peet: See also the new method added in my first answer

Comment: Contributing to an advanced regex I made ​​it myself and use htaccess to block ranges IPS, might help you.    

    Regex IP = ([2][5][0-5]|[2][0-4][0-9]|[1][0-9][0-9]|[0][0][0-9]|[0][1-9][0-9]|[0][0-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[0][0-9]|[0-9]\.[2][5][0-5]|[2][0-4][0-9]|[1][0-9][0-9]|[0][0][0-9]|[0][1-9][0-9]|[0][0-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[0][0-9]|[0-9]\.[2][5][0-5]|[2][0-4][0-9]|[1][0-9][0-9]|[0][0][0-9]|[0][1-9][0-9]|[0][0-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[0][0-9]|[0-9]\.[2][5][0-5]|[2][0-4][0-9]|[1][0-9][0-9]|[0][0][0-9]|[0][1-9][0-9]|[0][0-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[0][0-9]|[0-9])  

AAA.BBB.CCC.DDD

Comment: @D3F4ULT guess i got lost somewhere at 10-99 definition. nice regex, what does it block actually? or the other way round what ranges does one want to block on htaccess Level. most things i did control by rewrite rules while i am always interested in new ideas.

Comment: Some regex are unreliable, check out these <b>[0-9]{3}</b> or <b>[0-9]{2}</b> or <b>[0-9]{1}</b> or <b>[0-9]{1,3}</b> or <b>[0-9]{1,2}</b> or <b>[0-9]*</b>, the latter <b>[0-9]*</b> is wrong because if you set numbers 0 to 9, may have 999 and there is no such IP, the correct way is to imagine that the IP ranges from 0 to 255 and there "sub-ranges" to put the regex, check out this link to see if you can better understand this regex code is correct.

http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=81XLTdw7

Comment: @D3F4ULT interesting idea to use this for htaccess, thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basic structure for ip validation. Adapt as needed

```
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

    rem try some ip addresses 
    for %%i in ("1.1.1.1" "0.1.1.1" "250.1024.1.1" "10.0.2.1" "something" "" ) do (

        echo --------------------------------------------

        rem call with a variable to get return value
        call :validateIP %%~i ret 
        echo %%~i : return value : !ret! 

        rem call with or without variable to get errorlevel
        call :validateIP %%~i  && echo %%i is valid || echo %%i is invalid

    )   

    exit /b 

:validateIP ipAddress [returnVariable]
    rem prepare environment
    setlocal 

    rem asume failure in tests : 0=pass 1=fail : same for errorlevel
    set "_return=1"

    rem test if address conforms to ip address structure
    echo %~1^| findstr /b /e /r "[0-9][0-9]*\.[0-9][0-9]*\.[0-9][0-9]*\.[0-9][0-9]*" >nul

    rem if it conforms to structure, test each octet for rage values
    if not errorlevel 1 for /f "tokens=1-4 delims=." %%a in ("%~1") do (
        if %%a gtr 0 if %%a lss 255 if %%b leq 255 if %%c leq 255 if %%d gtr 0 if %%d leq 254 set "_return=0"
    )

:endValidateIP
    rem clean and return data/errorlevel to caller
    endlocal & ( if not "%~2"=="" set "%~2=%_return%" ) & exit /b %_return%
```

Comment: hello, as always you show very smart code, thank you, while it would need aacini's part too and switches for the function to control wether IP or subnets get validated. don't know if i will or would get this all together working. too i am burned with errorlevels in loops, i remember i had a lot of trouble with them in my script for dns-routing-monitor.

Answer (score 1):

there is no GNU BRE to validate dotted IPs. `FINDSTR`s REGEX capabilities are below that. You can use [grep for Windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/grep.htm) and GNU ERE:

```
ECHO(%IP%|GREP -E "(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[1-9]?[0-9])\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[1-9]?[0-9])\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[1-9]?[0-9])\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[1-9]?[0-9])"&&ECHO %IP% IS VALID/||%IP% IS NOT A VALID IP.
```

Comment: tnx for suggestion while often in corporate environment installation of Software or modules is not allowed - thus i have to admit to do this with windows built in functionallity. maybe XHR via JScript could offer more functionallity. @rojo what do you think, is this possible?

Comment: @peet instead grep rather use the [findrepl.bat](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=27024&sid=0a4d39a4fad34e53a817dbe38368c9bb#p27024) script by Aacini.

Comment: tnx for providing link, very impressing work Aacini did there and i will keep this in mind, although i will need to read it twice more to get it really :)

Answer (score 1):

I assumed you want to review IP numbers placed *inside a text file*. If the IP's appear at fixed positions inside lines in the file, for example, at third token like this:

```
IP number: 172.16.0.0/12
```

Then you may extract the IP number and separate its parts with a FOR /F command, and then review they in any way you wish:

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set wantedNumbers=0,128,192,224,240,248,252,254,255

for /F "tokens=3" %%n in ('findstr /r "[0-9][0-9]*\.[0-9][0-9]*\.[0-9][0-9]*\.[0-9][0-9]*" theFile.txt') do (
   for /F "tokens=1-4 delims=./" %%a in ("%%n") do (
      if %%a neq 255 echo First octet is not 255 & goto error
      if "!wantedNumbers:%%b=!" equ "%wantedNumbers%" echo Second octet bad & goto error
      if "!wantedNumbers:%%c=!" equ "%wantedNumbers%" echo Third octet bad & goto error
      if "!wantedNumbers:%%d=!" equ "%wantedNumbers%" echo Fourth octet bad & goto error
      echo The IP %%n is correct
   )
)
```

If the IP numbers are *not* at fixed positions, you need another, existent solution.

However, if the IP is stored in an individual variable (you have *not* indicated this point), just eliminate the first `for` and replace `%%n` by the value of the variable.

**EDIT**: *New method added*

Edit 2: List of numbers/ranges added

I devised a different way to solve this problem via the following subroutine:

```
@echo off

rem ValidateIP.bat: Validate an IP4 address
rem Antonio Perez Ayala

if "%~1" neq "" goto validateIP

echo Validate an IP4 address using several successive testings on it
echo/
echo call ValidateIP.bat ipAddress 1:ipRange1 2:ipRange2 ... N:ipRangeN
echo/
echo Each ipRange is comprised of an "errorlevel" followed by a colon and
echo 4 groups separated by dots of anyone of the following:
echo/
echo    - An asterisk, that match any value between 0 and 255.
echo    - A number, that match just that value.
echo    - Two numbers separated by hypen, that match any value in that range.
echo    - A list of numbers and/or ranges separated by number-sign (#).
echo/
echo At end, the value placed before the colon of the *last* matching ipRange
echo is returned in ERRORLEVEL; two or more ipRanges may return the same value.
echo If no ipRange is given, 1:*.*.*.* is assumed.
echo If no ipRange is matched, return zero.
echo/
echo Some examples:
echo/
echo    call ValidateIp %%IPaddress%%  1:0-254.*.*.0-254  2:172.16-30.0-254.1-254
echo/
echo    set subNET=0#128#192#224#240#248#252#254#255
echo    call ValidateIP %%IPaddress%%  1:255.%%subNET%%.%%subNET%%.%%subNET%%
goto :EOF

:validateIP ipAddress [#:ipRange] ...

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
echo %~1| findstr /B /E /R "[0-9][0-9]*\.[0-9][0-9]*\.[0-9][0-9]*\.[0-9][0-9]*" > NUL
if errorlevel 1 exit /B 0
for /F "tokens=1-4 delims=." %%a in ("%~1") do set p1=%%a& set p2=%%b& set p3=%%c& set p4=%%d
set "ipRanges=%* "
set ipRanges=%ipRanges:* =%
if not defined ipRanges set ipRanges=1:*.*.*.*
set ipRanges=%ipRanges::*=:0-255%
set ipRanges=%ipRanges:.*=.0-255%
set return=0
for %%a in (%ipRanges%) do for /F "tokens=1,2 delims=:" %%b in ("%%a") do (
   set /A fields=0, i=0
   set ipRange=%%c
   for %%d in ("!ipRange:.=" "!") do (
      set /A this=0, i+=1
      set range=%%~d
      for %%e in ("!range:#=" "!") do for /F "tokens=1-3 delims=-" %%i in ("!i!-%%~e-%%~e") do (
         if !p%%i! geq %%j if !p%%i! leq %%k set this=1
      )
      set /A fields+=this
   )
   if !fields! equ 4 set return=%%b
)
exit /B %return%
```

Using previous subroutine, this particular problem may be solved this way:

```
set "subNET=0#128#192#224#240#248#252#254#255"
call ValidateIp %theIP% 1:0-254.*.*.0-254 2:10.0-254.0-254.0-254 2:172.16-30.0-254.1-254 2:192.168.0-254.0-254 3:127.0-254.0-254.0-254 4:255.%subNET%.%subNET%.%subNET% 5:0.*.*.*

if %errorlevel% equ 1 (
   set ret=public
) else if %errorlevel% equ 2 (
   set ret=private
) else if %errorlevel% equ 3 (
   set ret=local
) else if %errorlevel% equ 4 (
   set ret=subnetmask
) else if %errorlevel% equ 5 (
   set ret=sourcenetwork
) else (
   echo Invalid IP address
   goto :EOF
)
```

Or in this shorter way:

```
set i=0
for %%a in (public private local subnetmask sourcenetwork) do (
   set /A i+=1
   set result[!i!]=%%a
)

set "subNET=0#128#192#224#240#248#252#254#255"
call ValidateIp %theIP% 1:0-254.*.*.0-254 2:10.0-254.0-254.0-254 2:172.16-30.0-254.1-254 2:192.168.0-254.0-254 3:127.0-254.0-254.0-254 4:255.%subNET%.%subNET%.%subNET% 5:0.*.*.*

if defined result[%errorlevel%] (
   set ret=!result[%errorlevel%]!
) else (
   echo Invalid IP address
   goto :EOF
)
```

Comment: hello sir, i've just red your findrepl code, woww impressing, but i will need to read it a few more times to get it, if ever anyhow at all :) i was totally ignoring from where input will come from. one will need them from file, one other from input or return. so the idea was to have a function that will work on input leaving the getting the input behind just taking it's call and validate if the input is rather IP, subnet or trash. i did use false wording in first pseudo line by "find" the find was only in use to validate the octet Syntax in first place.

Comment: so MC ND did begin a possible structure for this function while it would need a lot more to get your part in it and the more the switches for select the functions options while keeping function working well.

Answer (score 0):

This is a **NEW** answer to the **NEW** question in this same topic!

As I said you in my comment I need to understand what is the supposed operation of the code in order to fix it (otherwise, how could I do that?), but you not gave me a single description of your **NEW** code, so I can only guess...

So I guess that `:validateIP` subroutine must return a numeric errorlevel value to the caller program as described in `exit /?` command, and that it optionally return a string variable to the caller's environment. The code below do that:

```
    :validateIP ipAddress [/ipRange] [returnVariable]

    rem prepare environment
    setlocal 

    rem Initialize ip range as public
    set ipCASE=public

    rem Process switches
    set "returnVar=%~2"
    rem If second parameter start with slash...
    if "%returnVar:~0,1%" equ "/" (
        rem It is the /ipRange
        set "ipCASE=%returnVar:~1%"
        set "returnVar=%~3"
    )

echo ipcase: %ipCase%

    rem asume failure in tests : 0=pass 1=fail : same for return/errorlevel
    set "_return=1"
    set "_returnlevel=1"

    rem test if address conforms to ip address structure
    echo %~1| findstr /b /e /r "[0-9][0-9]*\.[0-9][0-9]*\.[0-9][0-9]*\.[0-9][0-9]*" >nul

    rem if it conforms to structure, test each octet for range values
    if not errorlevel 1 for /f "tokens=1-4 delims=." %%a in ("%~1") do (
        if %%a gtr 0 if %%a lss 255 if %%b leq 255 if %%c leq 255 if %%d gtr 0 if %%d leq 254 set "_return=public"
        if %%a equ 10 if %%b geq 0 if %%b lss 255 if %%c geq 0 if %%c lss 255 if %%d gtr 0 if %%d leq 254 set "_return=private"
        if %%a equ 172 if %%b geq 16 if %%b lss 31 if %%c geq 0 if %%c lss 255 if %%d gtr 0 if %%d leq 254 set "_return=private"
        if %%a equ 192 if %%b equ 168 if %%c geq 0 if %%c lss 255 if %%d gtr 0 if %%d leq 254 set "_return=private"
        if %%a equ 127 if %%b geq 0 if %%b lss 255 if %%c geq 0 if %%c lss 255 if %%d gtr 0 if %%d leq 254 set "_return=local"
    )

    rem set errorlevels
    if "%ipCASE%"=="public"  if "%_return%"=="public"  (set "_returnlevel=0") else (set "_returnlevel=1")

    if "%ipCASE%"=="private" if "%_return%"=="private" (set "_returnlevel=0") else (set "_returnlevel=1")

    :endValidateIP
    rem clean and return data/errorlevel to caller
    endlocal & ( if not "%returnVar%"=="" set "%returnVar%=%_return%" ) & exit /b %_returnlevel%
```

However, when I tested this subroutine with your testing code I got strange results. I reviewed the entire code and discovered several problems not in the subroutine, but *in the testing code*; for example, `echo %errorlevel%` inside the main `for` loop always will show 0, and the invocation of `:validateIP ipAddress [/ipRange] [returnVariable]` don't follow this format in 3 of 4 cases and sometimes don't include the return variable, but the calling code always show it, etc...

Of course, these problems have no relation with the *original* theme of this topic nor with your last request and I already spent too much time in this matter, so I didn't solved they...

Comment: I did not know that it would be better to split a complex problem into several questions, sorry. Will do that in future. My Intension to handle it in one thread was to keep it follow-able for searching other user - will keep this possible by linking questions up in future then. Please follow with your answer to new case.

Comment: new question is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20604372/how-to-handle-several-function-switches-and-return-codes-of-errorlevel-and-strin)

Comment: I did add descriptions and echos to see vars, while the return cases are not working?

Comment: @peet: I am afraid I don't understand what you want. I strongly encourage you to _read your replies_. For example: "I reviewed the entire code and discovered several problems ... _in the testing code_...". If you want the subroutine to "return a numeric errorlevel value", _please_ read the description of `exit /?` command! Why you `set errorlevel=any value`? This is a [forbidden practice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20324481/errorlevel-doesnt-work-in-windows-xp-but-it-works-in-windows7/20325128#20325128)! And a long et cetera... Do you want to fix your code or _use a code that works_?

Comment: You were right, in the testing code have been errors, there have been lines where the switch was before the IP-variable. A copy and paste error i made. I corrected and appologize for your confusion and problems to get sencefull returns from it. If you take the actual code, all works fine. I do set errorlevel with only numeric value 0 or 1 - but, as the function accepts different Switches, the returned errorlevel has to correspond to the set switch and not to function run itself. Where do you see other values for errorlevel?

Comment: to set an errorlevel this would be nice code `if "%_returnlevel%"=="0" (ver > nul) else (set dummy 2> nul)` why does nobody write this as clear as it is? while i DO not set any errorlevel directly and `Exit /b` allows numeric values?

Comment: @peet: I think `exit /?` and `if /?` descriptions are clear enough: the errorlevel is a number returned by EXIT command. Why you want more? I am sorry, but I will no longer aid you in the modification of your code. I will, however, gladly help you to use my `ValidateIP` subroutine that appear in [my first answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20299266/ip-verification-in-batch-script-first-match-by-findstr-secondly-verify-by-for/20301833#20301833) to this topic, below **EDIT**: _New method added_

Comment: I needed a while to understand your concerns. The setting of errorlevel was totally unneeded in my code as i did already return a number by exit /b correctly. You could have told me to just `REM` that line, as it was unneccessary. I now did use a correct way to set the errorlevel (like you showed my in your link) while this makes the return number of exit unneccessary.

Comment: Now implemented both ways, as i find this intersting for others.