# %errorlevel% doesn't work in Windows XP. But it works in Windows7

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, errorlevel

%errorlevel% doesn't work in WindowsXP.

As I know when an error occurs %errorlevel% set 1 or above value, and if there is no error it will set 0.

But, even though there is no error, %errorlevel% is 1. 
And I set %errorlevel% 0, even there is an error %errorlevel% is sill 0.

I think OS doesn't change %errorlevel% in XP.

In Win7 it work totally.

```
@echo off

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

call dir
echo errorlevel=%errorlevel%
REM expected errorlevel=0 but 1

call dor
echo errorlevel=%errorlevel%
REM expected errorlevel=1

set errorlevel=0
call dor
echo errorlevel=%errorlevel%
REM expected errorlevel=1 but 0
```

But if errorlevel 1 () looks work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

some examples for you:

```
@ECHO OFF &SETLOCAL
echo errorlevel=%errorlevel%
call dir >nul
echo errorlevel=%errorlevel%
```

---

output:

```
errorlevel=0
errorlevel=0
```

---

---

```
@ECHO OFF &SETLOCAL
echo errorlevel=%errorlevel%
call dor
echo errorlevel=%errorlevel%
```

---

output:

```
errorlevel=0
'dor' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
errorlevel=1
```

---

---

```
@ECHO OFF &SETLOCAL
::set errorlevel=0 illegal operation!
set test=1
set test
echo errorlevel=%errorlevel%
call dor
echo errorlevel=%errorlevel%
```

---

output:

```
test=1
errorlevel=0
'dor' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
errorlevel=1
```

`set errorlevel` is not a legal command. If you need to set the errorlevel system environment variable, do this with a usual command.

---

---

```
@ECHO OFF &SETLOCAL
::set errorlevel=1 illegal operation!
set test
echo errorlevel=%errorlevel%
call dir >nul
echo errorlevel=%errorlevel%
```

---

output:

```
Environment variable test not defined
errorlevel=1
errorlevel=0
```

Answer (score 4):

It usually happens when errorlevel is manually set. It is suppossed to be a dynamic variable, but when you set it to a value, checks for its content will return not the correct errorlevel value, but the value you set to it.

If in your command line you type `set errorlevel` and a variable is shown, then this is your problem. Clear the variable (`set errorlevel=`) and everything will work until a value is set again.

Answer (score 2):

Besides the points stated in previous answers, you must be aware that there are certain internal commands that does *not* change the errorlevel value in certain cases. If in doubt, you should do a small test before assuming that the errorlevel value changed after a certain command. An easy way to set the errorlevel to 0 is using `ver` command:

```
ver > nul
rem Here the errorlevel value is always 0
```

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20325128/5047996), the problem in your code sample is the `set errorlevel=0`.
To set the `errorlevel` to any arbitrary value use:

```
cmd /C exit 0 & rem to set errorlevel to 0 (same as omitting the number)
cmd /C exit 1 & rem to set errorlevel to 1
```

Alternative ways:

```
rem Reset `ErrorLevel`:
ver > nul
cd .
dir > nul
type nul
verify > nul
(call )

rem Set `ErrorLevel` to `1`:
color 00
set = 2> nul
(call)
rem (many other internal commands with missing/invalid arguments)
```